# zend: baseUrl view helper returns empty string

Tags: zend-framework, base-url

On my site, when I call `$this->baseUrl()` in a view, it returns an empty string. I would expect it to return e.g. `http://www.foobar.com/`. Do I need to manually set base url?

In manual to [Zend_Application_Resource_Frontcontroller](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html) - configuration keys, I have just found this:

> baseUrl: explicit base URL to the application (normally auto-detected)

Any ideas why it is not autodetected for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `baseUrl()` helper returns the path to your Zend Application.

Use the `serverUrl()` helper for the hostname.

Answer (score 2):

Did you set the baseurl in your application.ini?

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/subdir"
```

[Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html)